# What is the best way to add data to big list of labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a web page (Django form) that has about 150 questions, each question has a code (e.g. P10, P20, P30, etc), in Django, i know that i can set the verbose name with the code before label, but i want to wrap the question code in span before label, so i did it in javascript this way:

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('label[for="id_interview_date"]').prepend('<span class="code">P.20</span>');
    })
}) (django.jQuery);
```

but the problem now this file contains about 150 lines of code, and it's taking long time for the page to load, and to load the codes before the label.

What is the best way to achieve this with less lines of code?

Comment: It's not the amount of code that's the issue, it's looping over 150 elements. However you code it, that's what will have to happen. You will probably see some performance improvement if you use native JS instead of jQuery. The best solution will always be to modify your source HTML.

Comment: 150 elements shouldn't take long at all .... how much difference in loading time is there between loading it without the `prepend`?

Comment: It's not that much deference, the main problem is when the page load, it takes about 2-3 seconds for the "codes" to load. i've another javascript code (and it's quite long too - i replaced some default fields with another ones, and that also taking another few hundreds of code lines). i think i'll better look for how to make JS function that reads 2 arrays (labels, and label codes, and assign them to each other).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can copy your form, prepend spans before labels, and after render this new form on the page.

```
var $form = $('form').clone();
$('label', $form).each(function(){$(this).prepend('<span>P20/span>');});
$('form').replaceWith($form);
```